# How can i destroy memory in my mex files when variables are destroyed in matlab?

Tags: matlab, mex

I am handling some memory in my mex files and passing a handle back to matlab. Are there a way to deal with the event of a user clearing or deleting that specific handle stored in a variable in matlab, such I know it can be deleted in the mex file also.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? Usually you pass arguments into the mex file yourself so you can test if they exist with the exist() function before calling the mex function.

Comment: I allocate some memory on the GPU and returns a pointer to matlab. In matlab this is shown as X has some uint64 value. If i delete X in matlab. The memory is still allocated on the gpu. I would like to have some way of triggering when users delete or overwrite the variable X in matlab.

Comment: So after the mex file returns the pointer to the memory on the gpu, how do you do arithmetic on the memory in the gpu? Do you call another mex function?

Comment: I call the same mex function. It takes a handle to my manager, and a string telling what operation, and then extra arguments. I would example have Handle_C = ocl_mex(handle,'mat_mult',Handle_A, Handle_B). I dont see how that is relevant though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to link the lifespan of allocations managed inside your MEX layer to the lifecycle of the M-code level structures that are using them. You probably want to wrap those raw `uint64` handle values in a Matlab data structure that supports cleanup callbacks.

You could wrap them in a Matlab `handle` subclass that you define, and give it a `delete` method that calls your `ocl_mex` to do the appropriate cleanup. `Delete` is a destructor and will automatically get invoked when the last copy of the object is cleared from the Matlab workspace. (And once you're using objects, you could provide more concise methods corresponding to the various ocl_mex calling forms, a nicer display, maybe `*` syntax for multiplication using operator overloads, and so on.) See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html for details. This can work nicely if you then make the mex function a private function inside the class. Makes it easy to add debugging logging and sanity checks around your mex access, etc.

The code could look a little like this.

```
class ocl < handle
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        ocl_handle  # the raw uint64 handle the MEX layer works with
    end
    methods
        function out = ocl(mex_handle) # maybe make this private
           out.ocl_handle = mex_handle;
        end
        function delete(obj)
            if ~isempty(obj.ocl_handle)
               ocl_mex(obj.ocl_handle, 'cleanup');
            end
        end
        function out = mat_mult(A, B)
           handle_c = ocl_mex('mat_mult', A.ocl_handle, B.ocl_handle);
           out = ocl(handle_c); # And now the new handle has a cleanup hook, too...
        end
    end
    methods (Static = true)
        function out = allocate(some_args)
            new_handle = ocl_mex([], 'allocate', some_args);
            out = ocl(new_handle);
        end
    end
end
```

If you want to avoid using classes, you can also stick them in a plain struct and use `onCleanup` to create a callback that automatically gets invoked when the last copy is cleared.

The gotcha is that you have to make sure all access to the handle goes through the object or struct, and nothing pops it out and "leaks" the raw handle value. Easier to enforce with objects.

Comment: Thats what i really wanted in the first place but could not find what i was looking for. I had created the cleanup method on my mex, but my problem was that if the user deleted the handle, he had no way to call the cleanup. Thanks i will use this approach.